# Virtual Environment and Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I am using Atom IDE for working with Python along with Scripts package. I have created a virtual environment in my folder and want to use the packages in the same to work with Scripts.

Steps I have taken:

1. Activate the environment and start the atom from cmd with `atom .` command
2. Use `atom-python-virtualenv` for selecting the virtual environment and then trying to run with Scripts package.

However in both cases the packages (installed in virtualenv) result in an import error. Am I missing something?